# Incorrect remove from List using while() in C

Tags: c, list

I wrote a few function for my list: pushBack (implementation), print and remove(). 
When I'm doing implementation and removing of elements it works perfect with while() and for() (see the code) when I defined struct clientList list = { 0 }.

My structures:

```
struct listElement
{
    SOCKET socket;
    struct listElement *next;
};

struct clientList
{
    struct listElement* head;
};
```

I debug that little project for my client-server application to keep client sockets in list. Then I'm trying to remove values after struct listElement* currentElement = list.head using while. If It's left 3 5 7 9 it should be deleted 3 and 9 but they are still in the list => the function works wrong.

What value it must return? With int remove() and return 0 it also works good. It's very important to make it work this way.

Here is all my code:

```
int pushBackClient(struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket)
{
    struct listElement* newClient = (struct listElement*)malloc(sizeof(struct listElement));
    struct listElement *currentElement = list->head;
    newClient->socket = socket;
    newClient->next = 0;

    do
    {
        if (list->head == 0)
        {
            list->head = newClient;
            break;
        }
        while (currentElement->next != 0)
        {
            currentElement = currentElement->next;
        }
        currentElement->next = newClient;
    } while (false);
    return 0;
}

listElement removeFromList(struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket)
{
    struct listElement **currentElement = &list->head;

    while (*currentElement != 0 && (*currentElement)->socket != socket)
    {
        currentElement = &(*currentElement)->next;
    }

    if (*currentElement != 0)
    {
        struct listElement *tmp = *currentElement;
        *currentElement = (*currentElement)->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    return *(listElement*)currentElement;
}

void print(struct clientList *list)
{
    struct listElement* currentElement = list->head;
    while (currentElement != 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", currentElement->socket);
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }
}

int getNumOfClients(struct clientList *list)
{
    struct listElement* currentElement = list->head;
    int count = 0;
    for (currentElement = list->head; currentElement != 0;  currentElement = currentElement->next)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int N = 10;
    struct clientList list = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        pushBackClient(&list, i);
    }
    print(&list);
    printf(" - NUM = %d\n", getNumOfClients(&list));

    /*for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) removeFromList(&list, i);
    }*/

    int i = 0;
    // It's important to implement using WHILE because
    // is should delete 3 and 9 but it doesn't happen
    while (i < N)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            removeFromList(&list, i);
        }
        i++;
    }

    print(&list);
    int num = getNumOfClients(&list);
    printf(" - NUM = %d\n", getNumOfClients(&list));

    struct listElement* currentElement = list.head;

    while (currentElement != 0)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            removeFromList(&list, i);
        }
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }
    removeFromList(&list, 1); 
    print(&list);
    printf(" - NUM = %d\n", getNumOfClients(&list));
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for all occurrences of `listElement`, replace with `struct listElement`.  (or create a typedef)

Comment: You are making your world too complex with your `**currentElement`. Just use single indirection to walk the list, then use additional indirection to remove the element. A `free(tmp)` seems also wrong and should be `free(*tmp)`. Finally, the element before the one found still points to the `tmp` you delete.

Comment: How does that even compile?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general!

Comment: @ryyker it's everywhere instead of returned value of remove() function. Replaced, nothing changed. 
I even tried to make the type of the function listElement removeFromList(struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket). Not sure if it should work, I used to do that when I wrote ringBuffer. As I'm new in programming, it made me a lot of problems too ;)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie When I did with only poiunter to currentElement I had memory access violation and had an exception while removing. I'll try to make in simplier

Comment: @ErikW - by replacing all `listElement`, replace with `struct listElement`, it compiles fine.   In _my_ environment I had to comment out `system("pause");`, change `%d` to `%llu` and `false` to `FALSE`, but that is all implementation specific stuff.  Once that all was done, it ran without error, just does not have OP's expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is found. It works correct with this code:

```
    struct listElement* currentElement = list.head;
    while (currentElement != 0)
    {
        if (currentElement->socket % 3 == 0)
        {
            currentElement = removeFromList(&list, i);
            if (currentElement == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentElement = currentElement->next;
        }
    }
```

The function:

```
struct listElement * removeFromList(struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket)
{
    struct listElement *currentElement = list->head;
    struct listElement *prevElement = NULL;
    struct listElement *returnPointer = NULL;
    while (currentElement != 0 && currentElement->socket != socket)
    {
        prevElement = currentElement;
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }

    if (currentElement != 0)
    {
        struct listElement *tmp = currentElement;
        if (prevElement == 0)
        {
            list->head = currentElement->next;
            returnPointer = list->head;
            free(currentElement);
        }
        else 
        {
            prevElement->next = currentElement->next;
            returnPointer = prevElement->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return returnPointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If to make the code to be compiled then the problem with the while loop is the following

```
i = 0;
while (currentElement != 0)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        currentElement = removeFromList(&list, i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

The first value of `i` for which the function `removeFromList` is called is equal to 0 because 0 % 3 is equal to 0.

However the node with the value equal to 0 is not found in the list. (All nodes with even values were already removed in the previous while loop).

So the function returns a null pointer because the node is not found and the while loop stops its iterations.

Or if to consider your original loop

```
while (currentElement != 0)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        removeFromList(&list, i);
    }
    currentElement = currentElement->next;
}
```

then you forgot to initialize and to increase the variable `i`. It is always equal to `N` that is to `10`.

Here is the function implementation as you imagine it.

```
struct listElement * removeFromList(struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket)
{
    struct listElement **currentElement = &list->head;

    while (*currentElement != 0 && (*currentElement)->socket != socket)
    {
        currentElement = &(*currentElement)->next;
    }

    if (*currentElement != 0)
    {
        struct listElement *tmp = *currentElement;
        *currentElement = (*currentElement)->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    return *currentElement;
}
```

The problem with the function implementation is that it is impossible to distinguish whether the target node was not found or the tail node was removed.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I've realised the function, see in my answer :)